# wireshark-How to convert the ip into hostname using tshark

Tags: unix, wireshark, hostname, tshark

I used the below command to get the list of IP address of various entity,but i am not able to convert (identify) the hostname.

```
 tshark -r test_call_1.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport  tcp
```

sample output

```
192.30.16.95    21      192.30.160.2    43118
192.30.16.95    21      192.30.160.2    43118
192.30.16.95    21      192.30.160.2    43118
192.30.160.2    45791   192.30.16.95    45431
```

Can any one guide me on how to resolve these ip's to hostnames?

Thanks in Advance

M.Muralidharan

Comment: 192.30.16.95    21      192.30.160.2    43118  (single line of the sample op)

Answer (score 0):

To get tshark to print hostnames you need to enable hostname resolution by specifying the '-N n' option and selecting the hostname fields instead of the ip address by using e.g '-e ip.src_host'.

For example:

```
tshark -r test_call_1.pcap -N n -T fields -e ip.src_host -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst_host -e tcp.dstport tcp
```